# Is this possible to validate xml against multiple xsd in python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml-validation

I need to validate an xml against multiple xsd's.

I can't input the xml or xsd here since its a confidential.

Assume there are 3  xsd

```
1. a.xsd
2. b.xsd
3. c.xsd

xml File:
value.xml
```

Now i found below code from python lxml to validate against the xsd

```
xmlschema_doc = etree.parse(xsd_path)
    xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)

    xml_doc = etree.parse(xml_path)
    result = xmlschema.validate(xml_doc)
```

Here the validation happens against one xsd, that completely understood.
But what if we have to combine all xsd against one xml validation?
Is there any way to resolve such case?

Appreciated for the help?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Create another XSD, which contains include/import tags for a.xsd, b.xsd, c.xsd (and no type/element definitions). Validate against this new XSD.